# google apps script how to get email of user who open my google form

Tags: google-apps-script

How to get user email from the user who open my form

I used  `getActiveUser()` and `getEffictiveUser()` but both got my mail not the user mail who open my form

Comment: You could get the email of the user only if the user submits the form using the [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getRespondentEmail()) object. Using Apps script, there is no option to get the user details before the form submission. Also the open event for Google Forms does not occur when a user opens a form to respond, but rather when an editor opens the form to modify it. Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). You might have to use a non-apps script library to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and there is no good solution.

The problem as i understand it is that when you share your form to someone else, the script is still running under your account, that is why it always gets your email.

If you would like to get his email, than you have to share him the script as well and than give it its authorization.

This solution is unfortunately not user-friendly. I hope this helped at least a bit. Good luck!

Comment: this answer does not explain well the issue nor the solution.

Comment: It kind of does actually, there is no work around: if you want a user email address you need to ask for it via the Authorization request box (which is automatically triggered if the email permissions is required in the onOpen() function).

Comment: @Liyali, The open event for Google Forms does not occur when a user opens a form to respond, but rather when an editor opens the form to modify it. Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Comment: Ok, thanks KRR for the precision. Note that it does not change the fact that it is not possible to get the email unless the user is asked for permissions or entered his email manually and send it (custom trigger).